# Как сделать блок html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, как сделать такой "блок", чтобы синюю точку можно было двигать, и ее значения передавались в js? Заранее спасибо[image]

Comment: смотрите в сторону `input range`.

Comment: в js не знаю но примерно что нибудь такое смогу написать

Comment: какое "такое"?)

Comment: @Павел Румянцев Попробуйте этот скрипт http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/

Comment: Ищите плагины по запросу "input range"

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен range input slider. Сам пользуюсь таким решением:
http://rangeslider.js.org/. Оно и стилизуется хорошо и в js умеет генерировать события при прокрутке, а также если надо, то можно настроить для задачи диапазона.